# Table cell editor does show editing cursor when called editCellAt

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a dialog which contains a table. The requirement is to show a cell in editable mode when dialog is showing. Following is the code

```
class MyDialog extends JDialog
{
    JTable tbl = new JTable(new Object[][]{new String[]{"a", "b"}, new String[]{"1", "2"}},  new String[]{"col1", "col2"});    

    public MyDialog(Frame frame)
    {
        add(tbl);
        setSize(300, 300);

        tbl.setCellEditor(new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextField()));
    }

    @Override
    public void setVisible(boolean b)
    {
        super.setVisible(b);
        if(b)
        {
            tbl.editCellAt(tbl.getRowCount() - 1, tbl.getColumnCount() - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Following is the way to show

```
MyDialog d = new MyDialog(parent);
d.setLocationRelativeTo(btn);
d.setVisible(true);
```

Problem is even the cell is in the edit mode the cursor does not appear in the text field until user click. But the text can be typed.

Any thing missing or wrong in this code?

Comment: Two things, try setting [`surrendersFocusOnKeyStroke`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setSurrendersFocusOnKeystroke(boolean)) to `true` and make sure the editor actually has focus in the window.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling `setVisible` doesn't make the window suddenly visible, but instead, schedules the window to become visible at some point the future.

You could use a combination of `requestFocusInWindow` and `SwingUtilities#invokeLater` to request that the cell editor be given focus at some point the future, for example...

```
@Override
public void setVisible(boolean b) {
    super.setVisible(b);
    if (b) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tbl.editCellAt(tbl.getRowCount() - 1, tbl.getColumnCount() - 1);
                tbl.getEditorComponent().requestFocusInWindow();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I'd also be tempted not to override `setVisible` but instead use a `WindowListener`, but that's me

Comment: Both suggestions are working. Yes WindowListener approach seems much better

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  But long after setVisible.  Wrapping the call in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` doesn't seem to help. -- The cell editing works, but there's just no cursor unless you click.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what I am looking for!